# Radio button usando ViewData para uma model MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Possuo uma ViewData e gostaria de transforma-la em um RadioButton para uma model

```
ViewData["tiposPagamento"] = dbo.TiposPagamento.Where(_=>_.Ativo);
```

Radio Button :

```
  @Html.RadioButton(m=>m.TipoPagamentiID, ViewData["tiposPagamento"])
```

Porém só pega um item , pensei em fazer um foreach porem como é uma viewData teria que fazer um cast.
   E gostaria de saber como selecionar  o escolhido pelo usuario.

Answer (score 1):

O `@Html.RadioButton()` não aceita uma Collection.

Para ter algo parecido com o `RadioButtonList` você teria que implementar um helper.

Você pode dar sim um cast na `ViewData` e criar os Radio Buttons.

**Exemplo de como obter o escolhido pelo usuário**

```
ViewData["tiposPagamento"] = dbo.TiposPagamento.Where(_ => _.Ativo)
    .Select(e => new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Value = e.Id, 
        Text = e.Nome, 
        Selected = pagamentoSelecionadoId == e.Id 
    });

foreach (var item in ViewData["tiposPagamento"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
{
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.TipoPagamentoId, item.Value) @item.Text
    </div>
}
```